# Problem uploading images

Tags: bug, status-completed, images

When I tried to add this image from my computer at the main site,

[image]
I first got an error that the image (after uploading) couldn't be found, and then
this strange image showed up (screen snapshot):

[image]
I gave up and linked it to my own web server.

Comment: Last night it would not let me post a jpeg of Pascal's Triangle on an MSE question, but it worked fine this morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are aware of the image upload issues and are working on it here:  [Upload image isn't working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186430/upload-image-isnt-working)

Comment: Thanks, Geoff! $\mbox{}$